# Do you have to teleport the number of squares listed or is it a max range?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation

I had a little discussion about the distance my Swordmage can teleport after he used his `Vanishing Blade`. Its effect says (in part):

> Until the end of the encounter, whenever you hit an enemy with a melee attack, you may teleport 3 squares as a free action.

Of course, I can decide whether I want to take this free action or not, but what if I just want to teleport 2 squares?

So is the stated 3 squares an absolute distance or is it a range within which the destination of my teleport has to be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Teleportation is a type of movement that just has some special rules attached. All movement powers allow you to move any distance up to the number that follows the power, unless something relevant says otherwise. Teleportation's generic rules don't require that the entire movement value be used, and neither does your Swordmage's power.

So yes, it's a **range**, and you can move any distance from 1 to 3 squares with that power.